# How can I control class objects with different interfaces polymorphically?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism

```
public interface IAaa {
    public String search(String query);
}
public class DaoAaa implements IAaa {
    @Override
    public String search(String query){
         ....
         retrun "";
    }
}
```

I have this type of Dao classes from Aaa to Zzz. I can not make any modification to the source code. (I am just a client of the code.) Under the condition, how should I do to use the search method polymorphically?

I would like to do something like below.

```
public void doSomething() {
    List<xxxx> listXxxxx = new ArrayList<xxxx>();
    listXxxxx.add(DaoAaa);
    listXxxxx.add(DaoBbb);
    ....
    for(xxxx obj : listXxxxx){
        obj.search();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what your question means. Clarify, give a concrete example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Not sure to understand. Here you have ONE interface.

Comment: Do you mean that each DaoXxx has to implement a corresponding  interface IXxx?

Comment: It doesn't have to be that way. I would like to know the easy way to control all the DaoXxx objects polimophicaly since it has the same objective which is searching with a String.

Comment: I'm don't understand the question. Why @Eddy 's answer doesn't satisfy you? In that way you can refer to all Dao objects at once... Why do you need to split Dao in separeted lists if all have the same `search()` method? I'm not arguing, just curious.

Comment: Hi, All the concrete dao classes numbering about 50 have different interfaces even thought each dao has basically the same methods. the dao developer designed that way since they do not know anything about ood and I am developing the client program of the dao and have to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variable as the interface type and initialise it with an object of the desired concrete type; that is, `IAaa dao = new DaoAaa();`. When you call `.search()`, the implementation belonging to the concrete class will be called.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to do something like above.